# MySQL INNER JOIN. Pull data from one table with data from another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I am just getting started in learning how to do INNER JOINS correctly and I can't think of the best/easiest way to do this.

I am building a url shortener and I am trying to build a query that will get all long_url.destination's matching a slug "test". One slug might point to multiple long_url.destination's(URL shuffling, GEO matching, etc...). So I need the slug to get all long_url.destination's with the same short_url.slug.

Before I was running another query to get the short_id from the slug, then running another query to select all rows in long_url that had a matching short_id.

I think it might be quicker if I use an inner join, but I am unsure how to properly set it up.

I want to get all destination columns in table long_url with only the slug data in short_url without having to run a separate query to get the short_id from the slug.

```
Table: short_url
Columns: short_id | slug | enabled | timestamp
example:     1      test     1        1323343922

Table: long_url
Columns: long_id | short_id | destination          | geo | enabled |    timestamp
example:    1         1      http://www.test.com      US        1       132334922
example:    2         1      http://www.test.co.uk    UK        1       132334922
```

I got this so far:

```
SELECT destination, geo FROM long_url INNER JOIN short_url 
ON long_url.short_id = short_url.short_id WHERE enabled = 1;

function get_long_urls($slug) {

  $query = "SELECT....";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array(':slug' => $slug));
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return (array) $results:

}

example $results = array(
                        'http://www.test.com' => 'US',
                        'http://www.test.co.uk' => 'UK',
                         );
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me.  What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: I had to add WHERE slug = :slug to the query. Otherwise, I was just seeing if there was a more efficient/faster way to do it. So far this works fine, I just wanted to see if I was using the correct JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select long_url.destination
     , long_url.geo
  from long_url
inner
  join short_url
    on long_url.short_id = short_url.short_id
 where short_url.slug = :slug
   and long_url.enabled = 1
```

You don't need to qualify all column names like I did, because in this particular query there wasn't any ambiguity. All I really did is add a bound parameter placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT destination, geo FROM long_url LEFT JOIN short_url 
ON (long_url.short_id = short_url.short_id) WHERE enabled = 1
```